# How to formalize exceptions?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'd like to formalize the following in First Order Logic (FOL).

In ISO/IEC 14882:2014(E) on page 355 we have [image]
and later on page 356 we have [image]

This implies that for an expression E of the form "noexcept ( *expression* )", E is not type-dependent even if *expression* is type-dependent.

For a sentence of the form $$\text{if }\phi\text{ then }\psi,\text{ except if }\rho\text{ then }\mu$$ I would formalize it as $$\left[\neg \rho\implies(\phi\implies \psi)\right]\wedge\left[\rho\implies \mu\right]$$
Or similarly
$$\text{For every }x, \psi(x)\text{ if }\phi(x)\text{ except for every }x, \text{ if }\rho(x)\text{ then }\mu(x)$$
formalized as
$$\forall x:\left[\neg\rho(x)\implies(\phi(x)\implies\psi(x))\right]\wedge \left[\rho(x)\implies\mu(x)\right]$$

In this setting

$\phi(x):=$ $x$ has a type-dependent subexpression

$\psi(x):=$ $x$ is type-dependent

$\rho(x):=$ $x$ is of the specified form

$\mu(x):=$ $x$ is not type-dependent

**Question:**

Am I completely off track or is this the correct formalization?

Comment: Your formalization looks good to me.

Comment: @RobArthan what do you think, could we generalize this to describe "cancellable statements" like "unless otherwise stated x denotes a real number"? I'm thinking like a statement $\forall \Gamma: \neg\left( \Gamma \vdash \neg \phi \right) \implies \left(\Gamma \vdash \phi\right)$

Comment: Your formalization is good for the specific case in point. For formalizing notions like "unless otherwise stated" in general, you need to look into [non-monotonic logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-monotonic_logic).